# How can I have react batch multiple setStates for fetched data from useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still trying to wrap my head around how react handles renders and this particular behavior has had me scratching my head all day.  When i run this code, I get 3 console logs.  The first is a null, as expected since useEffect didn't run yet.  Next, I get the fetched worldData array from my api call as expected.  However, I then get a third console log with the same said array, which leads me to believe my component is being rerendered.  If I add another set state and another api call, I see yet another console log.

```
function App() {

  const [worldData, setWorldData] = useState(null)
  const [countriesData, setCountriesData] = useState(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const [world, countries] = await Promise.all([
        fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries?yesterday=true").then(res => res.json()),
        fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all?yesterday=true").then(res => res.json())
      ])
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
      setWorldData(world)
      setCountriesData(countries)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  console.log(worldData);
```

It seems like react is rendering every time I set a State, which is what I assume it's designed to do. However, I've read elsewhere that react batches multiple set states together when set together in useEffect.  So why is my set states not being batched then?  Is it because of the asynchronous code?  If so, is there a way I can fetch multiple endpoints and set all the retrieved data simultaneously so that my component only needs to rerender once?

Answer (score 0):

A couple bits

(1) If you're ONLY concerned about having a single state update then you can defined a single state and update that as such

```
const [fetched_data, updateFetchedData] = useState({world:null, countries:null});
...
// where *world* and *countries* are variables containing your fetched data
updateFetchedData({world, countries})
...
fetched_data.world // using the fetched data somewhere
```

(2) HOWEVER, your code should not care about receiving multiple updates and should cater for it as such...

Your useState should define what an empty result would look like, for example instead of

```
const [worldData, setWorldData] = useState(null); // probably shouldn't look like this
```

how about

```
const [worldData, setWorldData] = useState([]); // this is what an empty result set looks like
```

And inside whatever component that uses both *world* and *countries* data ( I assume one references the other which is why you want both updates at once), just put a conditional statement that if it's not found then put some string 'Loading' or 'NA' or whatever until it's loaded.